# Life cycle configuration was not coverd?

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse, sonarqube

Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (execution: default-compile, phase: compile)forced

Comment: can any one help me to solve this?

Comment: Please elaborate more on what you did, and what you expected.

Comment: when i was trying to associate with sonar it is showing empty groupid and articaftid, so i created pom.xml for groupid and articraftid. the pom.xml file was showing the following error

Comment: can u give the steps to integrate sonar with eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the corresponding wiki page of M2E that contains a very detailed explanation of this message:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered